# Working in flutter need solution for recording sound with wave form and forward it by 15 seconds

Tags: android, flutter

Working in flutter need solution for recording sound with wave form and forward it by 15 seconds ,

I tried many solutions but they were not helpful like using duration custom or custom.....

following code was tried but i did not get desired output and this is the last attempt by me to solve my issue but as usual did not get output so i opted this platform to get help on this issue
if anyone can solve or even provide a hint please respond as soon as possible .

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:audio_waveforms/audio_waveforms.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:smilestone/Audio_Screen/AudioRecordingProvider.dart';
import 'package:smilestone/Utils/sizeConfig.dart';

import '../Utils/utils.dart';

class AudioRecording extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioRecording({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AudioRecording> createState() => _AudioRecordingState();
}

class _AudioRecordingState extends State<AudioRecording> {
  RecorderController recorderController;
  PlayerController playerController;
  bool _isPlayingAudio = false;
  bool _isPlayIcon = true;
  bool closeIcon = false;
  bool yesDialog = false;
  String audioFilePath;
  TextEditingController saveController=TextEditingController();
  bool listOfSound=false;
  Duration currentPosition = Duration.zero;
  Duration _position = Duration.zero;
  Duration _duration = Duration.zero;


  var filePath;

  void toggleBtn() {
    if (_isPlayingAudio == false) {
      _isPlayingAudio = !_isPlayingAudio;
      _startRecording();
    }
    if (_isPlayIcon == false) {
      _isPlayIcon = !_isPlayIcon;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  void toggleIconBtn() {
    _isPlayIcon = !_isPlayIcon;
    _pauseAudio();
    if(_isPlayIcon==true){
      _pauseAudio();

    }
    print("object111111111");
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _initializeController() {
    recorderController = RecorderController()
      ..androidEncoder = AndroidEncoder.aac
      ..androidOutputFormat = AndroidOutputFormat.mpeg4
      ..iosEncoder = IosEncoder.kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
      ..sampleRate = 16000;

    playerController = PlayerController();
  }

  void _startRecording() async {
    try {
      if (!recorderController.isRecording) {
        await recorderController.record();
      } else {
        final path = await recorderController.stop();
        _isPlayingAudio = true;

        if (path != null) {
          await playerController.preparePlayer(path: path);
          await playerController.startPlayer(finishMode: FinishMode.loop);
        }
        setState(() {
          audioFilePath = path;
        });
      }
      setState(() {});
    }catch (e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void forwardAudioBy15Seconds() async {
    if (_isPlayingAudio) {
      var duration =  playerController.getDuration(DurationType.current);
      print("duration===>"+duration.toString());
      playerController.onPlayerStateChanged.skip(15000);
      // final Duration newPosition = currentPosition + Duration(seconds: 15);
      // playerController.seekTo(newPosition.inSeconds);
      // print("object"+newPosition.toString());

    }
  }




  Future<void> _saveAudio() async {
    final appDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final folderPath = '${appDir.parent.path}/audio_folder';
    final folder = Directory(folderPath);
    if (!(await folder.exists())) {
      await folder.create(recursive: true);
    }
    var audioFileName = "";
    if (saveController.text != null && saveController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      audioFileName = '${saveController.text}.wav';
    } else {
      audioFileName = 'audio_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.wav';
    }
    print("audioFileName"+audioFileName);
    filePath = '$folderPath/$audioFileName';
    print("file path"+filePath);
    final recordedAudioFile = File(audioFilePath);
    final copiedFile = await recordedAudioFile.copy(filePath);

    if (copiedFile != null) {
      print('Audio saved at: $filePath');
    } else {
      print('Failed to save audio.');
    }
    saveController.text="";

  }

  void _pauseAudio() async {
    if (_isPlayIcon) {
      playerController.pausePlayer();
      _isPlayingAudio=true;
    } else {
      playerController.startPlayer(finishMode: FinishMode.loop);
    }
    _isPlayIcon = !_isPlayIcon;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    recorderController.dispose();
    playerController.dispose();
  }

  Widget SelectListOfAudio(){
    return Container(
      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth *0.11,
      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.18,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        // border: Border.all(width: 0.5),
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.01,),
          GestureDetector(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/audioImage.png",
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.045,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.01,),
          GestureDetector(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/childImage.png",
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.045,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.01,),
          GestureDetector(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/child_animalImg.png",
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.045,
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth *0.088,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.055),
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/smileStone.png",
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.4,
                  )),

              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight*0.01,left: SizeConfig.screenWidth *0.055,right: SizeConfig.screenWidth *0.055),
                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.9,
                  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.7,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.18),
                            offset: Offset(0, 2),
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 8
                        )
                      ],
                      color: ColorCode_white_text,
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36)
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [

                      _isPlayingAudio
                          ? AudioFileWaveforms(
                        size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 400.0),
                        playerController: playerController,
                        enableSeekGesture: false,
                        waveformType: WaveformType.long,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        playerWaveStyle: const PlayerWaveStyle(
                          fixedWaveColor: Colors.grey,
                          liveWaveColor: Colors.black,
                          spacing: 12,
                          waveThickness: 7,
                          waveCap: StrokeCap.round,
                          scaleFactor: 1000,
                          showSeekLine: false,
                        ),
                      )
                          : recorderController.isRecording
                          ? Container(
                        width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.9,
                        height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.7,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.18),
                                  offset: Offset(0, 2),
                                  spreadRadius: 0,
                                  blurRadius: 8
                              )
                            ],
                            color: ColorCode_white_text,
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36)
                        ),
                            child: AudioWaveforms(
                              size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 500.0),
                              recorderController: recorderController,
                              enableGesture: false,
                              waveStyle: const WaveStyle(
                                bottomPadding: 205,
                                waveColor: Colors.black,
                                showDurationLabel: false,
                                waveCap: StrokeCap.round,
                                extendWaveform: true,
                                showMiddleLine: false,
                                scaleFactor: 400,
                                waveThickness: 6,
                                spacing: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                          : Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.04, left: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.05),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/backBtn.png",
                                    height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.03,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
                                  listOfSound=!listOfSound;
                                  setState(() {

                                  });
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.025, left: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.5),
                                  child: !listOfSound? Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/selectSound.png",
                                    height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.05,
                                  ):SelectListOfAudio()
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.02, right: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.02),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "assets/images/upload.png",
                                    height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.06,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text('Record your voice here'),

                        ],
                      ),
                      _isPlayingAudio?
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.025, left: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.05,bottom: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.025),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  showDialog(
                                    barrierDismissible: false,
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return AlertDialog(
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                        ),
                                        title: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              '''Are you sure you want to Delete this recording?''',
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: Utils().GlobalScreenHeight * 0.022, color: black_color, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.03,
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.25,
                                                  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.053,
                                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                        primary: greenColor, // Background color
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                                        _isPlayingAudio = !_isPlayingAudio;
                                                        setState(() {});
                                                      },
                                                      child: Text('Yes')),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.05,
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.25,
                                                  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.053,
                                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                        primary: redColor, // Background color
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                        if (_isPlayIcon == true) {
                                                          _pauseAudio();
                                                        }
                                                      },
                                                      child: Text('No')),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/wrong.png",
                                  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.025,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ChangeNotifierProvider<RecordingProvider>(
                              create: (_) => RecordingProvider(),
                              child: Consumer<RecordingProvider>(
                                builder: (context, provider,_){
                                  return Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.025, right: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.05),
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () async{
                                        await _pauseAudio();
                                        showDialog(
                                            barrierDismissible: false,
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                                ),
                                                title: Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Container(
                                                      width:SizeConfig.screenWidth* 0.5,
                                                      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.07,
                                                      child: TextFormField(
                                                        cursorColor: ColorCode_grey,
                                                        controller: saveController,
                                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.018),
                                                        decoration: InputDecoration(

                                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                color:  TextFormColor,
                                                              )
                                                          ),
                                                          hintText: "Name your recording",
                                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.018),
                                                          fillColor: TextFormColor,
                                                          filled: true,
                                                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                color:  TextFormColor,
                                                              )
                                                          ),
                                                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                                color:  TextFormColor,
                                                              )
                                                          ),

                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.02,),
                                                    Text("Successfully Saved!",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontSize: Utils().GlobalScreenHeight *0.02),),
                                                    SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.02,),
                                                    Container(
                                                      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.25,
                                                      height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.053,
                                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                            primary: greenColor, // Background color
                                                          ),
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            _saveAudio();
                                                            provider.FetchSaveRecording('${saveController.text}', filePath);
                                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                                            // _isPlayIcon = !_isPlayIcon;
                                                            setState(() {});
                                                          },
                                                          child: Text('Done')),
                                                    ),

                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            });
                                        setState(() {

                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        "assets/images/right.png",
                                        height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.025,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },

                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ):Container(),
                    ],
                  )
              ),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight *0.05,),

              _isPlayingAudio
                  ? Container(
                width: SizeConfig.screenWidth *0.8,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async{
                          await playerController.seekTo(1000);

                        },
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/backward.png",
                          height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.08,
                        )),
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: _pauseAudio,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          _isPlayIcon ? "assets/images/audio_pause.png" : "assets/images/audio_play.png",
                          height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.085,
                        )
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: ()async {
                          playerController.onCurrentDurationChanged.listen((duration) {
                            duration=5000;

                          });
                          forwardAudioBy15Seconds();
                          setState(()async {
                            Duration forwardDuration = Duration(seconds: 5);
                            await playerController.getDuration(DurationType.current);
                            forwardDuration.inSeconds;
// Seek forward by a specific duration
//                             Duration currentPosition =  playerController.getDuration(DurationType.current);
//                             Duration forwardDuration = Duration(seconds: 5); // Seek forward by 5 seconds
//                             Duration targetPosition = currentPosition + forwardDuration;
//
//                             if (targetPosition > playerController.) {
//                               // Adjust target position to the maximum duration if it exceeds the duration
//                               targetPosition = playerController.duration;
//                             }
//
//                             await playerController.seekTo(targetPosition);
                            var duration =  playerController.getDuration(DurationType.current);
                            print("duration===>"+duration.toString());

                          });
                        },
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/forward.png",
                          height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.08,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              )
                  : GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _startRecording();
                  },
                  child: Image.asset(
                    recorderController.isRecording
                        ?
                    "assets/images/audio_pause.png":
                    "assets/images/mic.png",
                    height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.085,
                  )),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.